# Pycharm relative path

Tags: python, pycharm

I want import import something  from **database and models** files

```
from ..database import SessionLocal
from ..models import Todos
```

and receive   [image]

```
 from ..database import SessionLocal
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Comment: Please share how you're running it.

Comment: uvicorn main:app --reload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great related comprehensive answer here: [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time/14132912#14132912) .

You can make an absolute import: `from TodoApp.database import ..`. Or also modify your `PYTHONPATH` configuration in Pycharm to add the directory where the modules are located (beware of name conflicts with stdlib modules in that case), and import them directly (without dots to indicate relative imports).